# Are there any embedded languages that can be embedded into C# and actionscript?

Tags: c#, actionscript, embedded-language

I'm looking for a embedded language that can be used to script common code between a server app written in C# and a client app written in Flash/Actionscript. It is important that the embedded language interpreter run natively in the environment it is embedded into.  For example, it cannot load any external C libraries (i.e. python, neko).

Does such a thing exist for these two languages?  Perhaps there is some minimal interpreter that could be easily ported to both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Javascript is the answer.

[Here's some thoughts](http://www.klynch.com/archives/000079.html) on calling Javascript from Actionscript and vice versa.

[Here's some words](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/3efc7bf9-730f-47d0-bc9c-7a3550cf1282/) about calling Javascript from C#.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably end up fairly ugly, but [someone has successfully embedded Lua into Actionscript through Alchemy](http://arcanearcade.blogspot.com/2008/12/lua-actionscript-alchemy.html) -- [demo on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/lua-alchemy/).  Pair that up with [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/projects/luainterface/) and you've got an embedded language on both sides.  You'll find a couple more "JavaScript (or ActionScript in Flash)" implementations of Lua on [the Lua Implementations page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations).

There's also [Pair](http://pair.collab.eu/), an AS3 implementation of Python that looks a lot more stable than Lua-Alchemy.  The .NET complement would be [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython).

[Haxe can output a .swf](http://haxe.org/doc/intro), which might suffice for your needs -- I'm not sure if two .swf files can communicate, I don't really use flash.  The big downside with Haxe is no native .NET support, although it can support Neko or C++, both of which you would have to go out of your way to integrate with .NET.